# How can I override automatically generated links in Atom feeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, atom-feed

My Atom feed automatically generates a `link` I want removed. How can I achieve that? This code:

```rails
atom_feed do |feed|
  feed.title @client.name
  @documents.each do |document|
    feed.entry document, published: document.created_at do |entry|
      entry.title document.title
      entry.content document.message
      entry.link share_url(@client.client_code, document.id)
      entry.url share_url(@client.client_code, document.id)
      entry.author @client.name
    end
  end
end
```

Generates this feed:

```xml
<entry>
  <id>tag:localhost,2005:Document/2694</id>
  <published>2014-04-25T11:36:34+10:00</published>
  <updated>2014-05-01T09:27:16+10:00</updated>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://localhost:3000/documents/2694"/>
  <title>April</title>
  <content>Whatever.</content>
  <link>http://localhost:3000/user/2694</link>
  <url>http://localhost:3000/user/2694</url>
  <author>User</author>
</entry>
```

Here's the offender I want removed (or at least changed):

```html
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://localhost:3000/documents/2694"/>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. You can pass a `url` argument into `feed` like this:

```
...
feed.entry document, published: document.created_at, url: share_url(document.user.client_code, document.id) do |entry|
...
```